# Variable args and keyword only args in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, keyword-argument

I was going thru PyTorch and found function signatures like

```py
 torch.zeros(*size, *, out=None, dtype=None, layout=torch.strided, device=None, requires_grad=False) → Tensor
```

Here the args after * are keyword only args and the size is a variable number of args.

My questions are

1. When I try to define a function in similar lines

```py
def function(*a, *, e=0, f=0):
    print (a, e, f)

function(1, e = 5, f = 6)
```

I get the following error

```sh
 File "main.py", line 2
    def function(*a, *, e=0, f=0):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

2. Also `torch.zeros` accepts `size` as keyword. How is this possible ?

```py
torch.zeros(size=(2,3))
```

AFAIK only these 2 should work

```py
torch.zeros((2,3))
torch.zeros(2,3)
```

Comment: `*a` already sucks up all positional arguments, any following arguments can only be keyword arguments. So a bare `*` is redundant and in fact a syntax error. Are you sure you've found that in actual PyTorch source code, or just in the documentation?

Comment: @deceze From the docs. I am unable to locate the code in the repo.

Comment: So it's just an inaccuracy in the docs, it's not actual code.

Comment: @deceze How to see the code for the function ?